# Source Code for strcpy and strcat

Tags: core-libraries

Does anyone know the location of the assembler file for strcpy and strcat for the Arduino?  I wish to modify it.

Comment: I don't think these functions are written in assembler, but just in pure C. I am not sure it would be agood idea to modify them (but you could copy them into new functions and adapt the way you want it). Honestly, these functions are quite easy to write with just 1 or 2 lines of code. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

The Arduino IDE doesn't ship with the source/assembly for a lot of the core functionality. It comes pre-compiled in object/library files.

However, you could download the source code for AVR Libc from this site:

- http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc

Obviously there's no guarantee that the files you download will exactly match what comes with the Arduino IDE, but it's useful if you're interested in how they're implemented.

When you've downloaded and extracted the source code, look in the `libc/string` folder. you should find assembly files called `strcat.S` and `strcpy.S`.

As jfpoilpret says in the comments, attempting to modify core library functions is generally not a good idea. They may be getting called by other parts of the core, so any changes you make could break something else.